# AFJSONRequestSerializer POST JSON Array

Tags: objective-c, json, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am trying to post to an API that is expecting a JSON array as input, for example:

```
[
  {
    "token": "bd3",
    "display_order": 0
  }
]
```

I am unable to get AFJSONRequestSerializer to produce this, my code to create the params :

```
 NSDictionary *campParams = @{@"token" : @"bd3", @"display_order" : @"0" };
 NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:campParams];
 NSDictionary *final = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arr forKey:@""];
```

Which creates the JSON as:

```
{"":[{"token":"bd55","display_order":"0"}]}
```

How can I modify my code to get the proper JSON output?  I am creating a second dictionary as the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager accepts parameters as a dictionary, not an array.

```
[manager PUT:url parameters:final success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //done
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Comment: After `NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:campParams];` you already have the correct object.

Comment: Why are you creating the second dictionary???????

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes.  And then know that a JSON "array" == NSArray and JSON "object" == NSDictionary.

Comment: Edited above so you can see what i am doing better

Comment: Why 2 down votes? Seems like a valid question to me!

Comment: Probably because you have not down the basic learning of [JSON](http://json.org).

Comment: I understand the JSON, the question is more related to how to get the AFNetworking framework to post it

Comment: Is the value of "display_order" in your JSON supposed to be a number or a string?

Comment: thats not important to this question, the main issue is the AFNetworking aspect

Comment: The point you're missing is that the operand is called "parameters:" -- you're not passing it a valid parameter dictionary.

Comment: "the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager accepts parameters as a dictionary, not an array" - then you're using a pretty old version of AFNetworking. You should update.

Answer (score 2):

Don't add the last dictionary operation, the questions shows that a JSON array is expected..

```
NSArray * jsonArray = @[ @{ @"token" : @"bd3", @"display_order" : @"0" } ];
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonArray options:0 error:&error];

NSLog(@"jsonData as String: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Output:

```
jsonData as String: [{"token":"bd3","display_order":"0"}]
```

There is a possibility that the last argument should be a number, not a string:

```
NSArray * jsonArray = @[ @{ @"token" : @"bd3", @"display_order" : @0 } ];
```

producing:

```
jsonData as String: [{"token":"bd3","display_order":0}]
```

which better matches your initial JSON example.

Here is an example but not using AFNetworking because I am not conversant in it:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                           if (connectionError) {
                               NSLog(@"Error: %@", connectionError);
                           }
                           else {
                               NSLog(@"data as String: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                           }
                       }];
```

Note: By all means use AFNetworking, it is great! I just know the older OSX/iOS methods by heart and I did not have a test project that already had AFNetworking installed.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to simply change the request serializer, I was not aware that it was not using JSON by default, so I changed it and now it works.